# Black Scholes model

Tags: finance

I am looking to program the Black Scholes model, but I don't understand how to write this equation as basic math.

- Equation => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes
- Known inputs => https://www.xignite.com/xRealTimeOptions.asmx?op=GetBlackScholesOptionValue

#### Example values

- Type: Put
- StockPrice: 19
- StrikePrice: 20
- YearsToMaturity: 0.16
- RiskFreeRate: 0.10
- Volatility: 0.60

I can get all of these inputs, but I just need to program the basic calculation, like (these are just made up numbers and equations)

> f = a + (b/c);
>   f * f = z;
>   z / 3 + ( f * a ) = m;
>
> m is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Espen Haug, the guy famous for his book on option formulas, implements Black Scholes in several languages/platforms [here](http://www.espenhaug.com/black_scholes.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very very easily in Excel. All you're doing is:

$C_t = S_t N(d_1) - N(d_2) K e^{-r(T-t)}$

where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are constants obtained through elementary calculations, $N(.)$ is the `NormSdist` function in Excel, and $S$, $K$ and $e^{-r(T-t)}$ are also easy to compute.

This is for a call; but it's almost the same thing as for a put.